# How to make this method only have 1 return statement instead of 2

Tags: java, methods, return

My professor has a rule that "there should be no more than one return statement in any method". Now I've written a pretty simple method in my first project. How would I make this have only return statement without ruining functionality?

```
public static int find(int correctNumber, int numArray[], int lastNum) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lastNum; i++) {
            if (numArray[i] == correctNumber) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
```

Comment: Store the answer in a variable and return it at the end of the method

Comment: I do understand where your teacher is coming from, because I was taught the same thing at one point. It does make the flow of control easier. However, in your case doing anything else but what you've done will make it longer and more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another variable to assign the value and then apply a break within the if clause to exit the loop.

```
public static int find(int correctNumber, int numArray[], int lastNum) {
        int returnValue = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastNum; i++) {
            if (numArray[i] == correctNumber) {
                 returnValue = i;
                 break;
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
}
```

And you will find that many professional programmers with lots of experience find it perfectly acceptable to use multiple return statements.

For example: This is the equals override from the `JDK HashMap` source.  That code was written by four internationally recognized computer scientists, three of which have their PhD's.

```
public final boolean equals(Object o) {          
    if (o == this)                               
        return true;                             
    if (o instanceof Map.Entry) {                
        Map.Entry<?,?> e = (Map.Entry<?,?>)o;    
        if (Objects.equals(key, e.getKey()) &&   
            Objects.equals(value, e.getValue())) 
            return true;                         
    }                                            
    return false;                                
}
```

Comment: Wow I had the biggest brain fart when I tried that. I made my returnValue = 0 at the beginning of the code and was getting a logic error (obviously). My professor doesn't let me use breaks either but fortunately I don't really "need" the break here. Regardless, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
public static int find(int correctNumber, int numArray[], int lastNum) {
    int correctIndex = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < lastNum; i++) {
        if (numArray[i] == correctNumber) {
            correctIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return correctIndex;
```

Comment: This won't work if the `if` condition is true multiple times. Add a `break`.

Comment: It depends on whether the requirements are "find first instance" or "find any instance".  This is not specified to us.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
public static int find(int correctNumber, int numArray[], int lastNum) {
    int temNum = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastNum; i++) {
        if (numArray[i] == correctNumber) {
            temNum = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return temNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int find(int correctNumber, int numArray[], int lastNum) {
    int i = lastNum - 1;
    while (i >= 0 && numArray[i] != correctNumber) {
        i--;
    }
    return i;
}
```

This differs slightly from your code in that, if the 'correctNumber' occurs twice, it will find the higher-index instance.

It could be expressed with a for-loop but I find I prefer the while-loop.

```
public static int find(int correctNumber, int numArray[], int lastNum) {
    int i;
    for (i = lastNum-1; i >= 0 && numArray[i] != correctNumber; i--) {
    }
    return i;
}
```